# How can I access the SignalSteength without using onSignalStrengthsChanged()?

Tags: android, signals, phone-state-listener

I want my application to protocoll, whether a connection to the web is possible plus the signal strength of the current GSM connection. I want to repeat this process about every minute.

At this point my Class looks like:

```
public class UmtsActivity extends Activity {
[...]
TelephonyManager Tel;
MyPhoneStateListener MyListener;    
int currentSignalStrength;

[...]



 private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
  @Override
  public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
  {
     super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
  currentSignalStrength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
  }
```

So far I only read the SignalStrength by using the onSignalStrengthsChanged() function of my phonestateListener. Is there any other way, so I can save CPU time?

Sincerly
Wolfen

Answer (score 1):

If you make the PhoneStateListener part of a service then you have a component of you app that always knows the current signal strength. The UI portion of the app can then query the service for the state on demand or have an update posted when the strength changes beyond some limit. For instance, signal strength changes rapidly - so only post an update if it changes by more than 10% or limit the updates by time.

For instance (here update only gets sent of the objects of interest are changed (mSms or mMins) and only every 5th signal strength change. The application's Activity will sink this Intent. This is called by the service's PhoneStateListener overridden methods.

```
/* called from the phone state listener to check for any changes in the number of sms/calls since last time
 * and to raise a suitable intent if required. Check the time to avoid calling too fast.
 */
private void update()
{
    final String key = getString(R.string.pref_periodstart_key);
    final String defVal = getString(R.string.periodstart_defaultValue);
    Thread thread = new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int start = Integer.valueOf(mPrefs.getString(key, defVal));
            Date date = PhoneUsageInfo.getLastContractDate(start);
            int mins = PhoneUsageInfo.getMinutesUsedSince(context, date);
            int sms = PhoneUsageInfo.getSMSCountSince(context, date);
            boolean changed = (mins != mMins || sms != mSms);
            if (changed || mCount % 5 == 0) {
                mMins = mins;
                mSms = sms;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.INTENT_USAGE_UPDATE);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SMS_COUNT, sms);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_MIN_COUNT, mins);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_START_DATE, date);
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("service sending broadcast intent sms %d, mins %d (%s)", sms, mins, changed?"changed":"unchanged"));
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
            mCount += 1;
        }
    }, "PhoneUsageServiceUpdate");
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Hi. I'd like to refresh the signalStrength only when I really need this information, like In case of a new connection. So far I only know onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) to read this information. I have no idea how to Access the SignalStrength directly.